# Removing Pandas duplicates with more complicated preference than first or last

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas .drop_duplicates lets us specify that we want to keep the first or last (or none) of the duplicates found. I have a more complicated condition. Let's say I have a set of preferred values for a column. If a duplicate pair is found and one is in the preferred set, I want to keep that one, regardless of whether its first or last. If both are preferred, usual drop_duplicates behavior should apply. If neither is in preferred set, then again, usual drop_duplicates behavior should apply.

I've tried playing with masks but can't seem to get it right. I think it might be the wrong way to go about it. Here's what I've tried.

```
import pandas as pd


def conditional_remove_duplicates(df, preferred_tags):

    duplicates_mask = df.duplicated(subset=['id', 'val'], keep=False)
    preferred_mask = df['tag'].isin(preferred_tags)
    mask = duplicates_mask | preferred_mask
    df = df[mask].drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'val'], keep='first')

    return df


data = {'id': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D'],
        'val': [10, 10, 11, 10, 20, 20, 30, 40, 40],
        'tag': ['X', 'Z', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'X', 'X', 'Z', 'Z']}
preferred_tags = {'X', 'Y'}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
"""
  id  val tag
0  A   10   X
1  A   10   Z
2  A   11   X
3  A   10   Y
4  B   20   Z
5  B   20   X
6  C   30   X
7  D   40   Z
8  D   40   Z
"""
result_df = conditional_remove_duplicates(df, preferred_tags)
print(result_df)
""" Produces:
  id  val tag
0  A   10   X
2  A   11   X
4  B   20   Z
6  C   30   X
7  D   40   Z

Should be:
   id  val tag
0  A   10   X
2  A   11   X
5  B   20   X
6  C   30   X
7  D   40   Z
"""
```

Comment: It's crossed my mind that sorting on ['id', 'val', 'tag'] could get me closer to a solution, but that's a pretty expensive operation on a large dataframe. I was hoping for a solution that has general applicability for dealing with problems of this type, i.e. conditional de-duplication.

Comment: sorting with the `preferred_mask` added, not the `tag`., is indeed the way to go. I'm not sure how large your dataframe is, but normally, if you can fit it in the memory, sorting is not that expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a column that indicates the priority you want to give to duplicates and sort based on that. They key here is to use `mergesort` so it's stable and doesn't swap order for current ties.

Then you can drop duplicates.

```
df['rank'] = df['tag'].isin(preferred_tags)
df = df.sort_values(by='rank', ascending=False, kind='mergesort')
df.drop_duplicates(['id', 'val'])

 id  val tag   rank
0  A   10   X   True
2  A   11   X   True
5  B   20   X   True
6  C   30   X   True
7  D   40   Z  False
```

Comment: I'd do it like this. The OP's comment under the question asks to not use `sort_values` though.

Comment: True, though at least here it's just a single sort, maybe there's a super other clever way to do it though might just be some under the hood sorting/organizing anyway

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant way that you were looking for but here is one way to do it

```
def conditional_remove_duplicates(df, preferred_tags):

   df = pd.DataFrame(list(pd.Series(df.itertuples(index=False)).drop_duplicates(keep='first')))
   duplicates_mask = df.duplicated(subset=['id', 'val'], keep=False)
   preferred_mask = df['tag'].isin(preferred_tags)
   mask = (~duplicates_mask | preferred_mask ).rename('mask')
   df = df[mask].drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'val'], keep='first')

return df
```

I'm quite new to Python, so any comments or suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)/[`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) for each "id/val" to mimic a `drop_duplicates(how="not preferred")` :

```
def pref_dup(g):
    return g.loc[[g.isin(preferred_tags).idxmax()]]

out = (
    df
     .groupby(["id", "val"])["tag"]
     .apply(pref_dup, include_groups=False)
     .reset_index(level=[0, 1])
)
```

Output :

```
  id  val tag
0  A   10   X
2  A   11   X
5  B   20   X
6  C   30   X
7  D   40   Z
```